# Flutter: Как после нажатия на кнопку открыть приложение Telegram с моим каналом?

Tags: flutter

Приложение на Flutter. Нужно чтобы пользователь нажимал на кнопку, затем открывалось приложение Telegram, в котором уже будет открыт какой-нибудь канал.

Есть некое решение, но оно открывает бразуер с телеграмом, а мне нужно открыть приложение Telegram https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68511745/how-do-i-open-a-telegram-chat-from-my-flutter-app